# Simple LDAP SSO auth

Tags: java, single-sign-on

I have a very simple LDAP auth :

```
DirContext ctx = null;
    try
    {
        logger.debug("Trying to log with LDAP");
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, ninjaProperties.get("ldapFactory"));
        env.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, ninjaProperties.get("ldapProvider"));
        env.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, ninjaProperties.get("ldapAuthentication"));
        env.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ninjaProperties.get("ldapDomain") + context.getParameter("login")); 
        env.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, context.getParameter("password"));


        ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

        if(ctx != null){
            logger.info( "User [" + context.getParameter("login") + "] logged in successfully." );
            ctx.close();
            return Results.redirect("/TermeController/consult");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {           
        logger.error("LDAP Login failed : " + e.toString());
    }
```

For now, users logg in with a form. I would like to set up an SSO auth, but i can't find a way to set it up easily.
Do i need to use something like CAS or so? Or is there a simple way?
Thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSO is quite a broad topic, I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve here. However if you want SSO for windows users i.e. allowing Windows users that are already authenticated against a domain controller to access your app with the same credentials you could look into [WAFFLE](http://dblock.github.io/waffle/) which does exactly that.

Comment: This is exctly what i'm trying to do, i'll try with waffle, thx =)